# URIError: Failed to decode param '/December%2015,%' in framework express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Using express framework I did a middleware that handles a URI with a date as parameter.

```
app.get("/:date",function(req,res){
     var result;
     var myDate=req.params.date

       if(moment(myDate).isValid()){
             //some code here
      } 

        else {
              //some code here
            }


  }
```

and the http is for example:
    https://theweb.com/December%2015,%2020

The middleware works well. But if the http finish in % as in
    https://theweb.com/December%2015,% 
it gives a error:

```
URIError: Failed to decode param '/December%2015,%'
```

and what I would like is to convert that error in the display of a message as Bad Request.

Answer (score 0):

You can register an error handler like this:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log('hit error handler');

    res.sendStatus(err.status || 500);
});
```

Note that the function must have 4 arguments, even if you don't use all of them. This function can then respond in whatever way you think is appropriate, in my example I've just sent back the status code. Express sets `err.status` to 400 for a `URIError`.

See https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

I had already use this middleware, but no result. It still gives same error when the URI is: https://myweb.com/December%2015,%

```
URIError: Failed to decode param '/December%2015,%'
```

Might be is the position of the code

```
var express = require('express');
var moment=require("moment")
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
       console.log('hit error handler');
       res.sendStatus(err.status || 500);
           });

app.get("/", function (request, response,next) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
       });

    app.get("/:date",function(req,res){

        var result; 

        var myDate=req.params.date //From here comes the error

       if(moment.unix(myDate).isValid()){
            // some code
            result={/*some code*/}
         } else if(moment(myDate).isValid()){
              //some code
              result={/*some code*/} 

        else {
              result={/*some code*/}
            }

        res.json(result)


    })
```